# How would i add more values in a option element with JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-select, htmlcollection

If someone could help me out with coding in JS. I have a Select element  with some Option values created in a HTML, also below i have a input field where i want to be able to add a a new Option value and also delete if i need to. I know that this could be achived trough the looping i guess, but since the DOM gives me a HTMLcollection of the elements of the Option list.So i know that i can achive that with the createELement in the DOM , but is it possible to do that different. My code is this below:

```
<select name="name" id="name">

    <option value="burim" class="someName">burim</option>
    <option value="eliot" class="someName">eliot</option>
    <option value="saska" class="someName">saska</option>

</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="add">
<br><br>
<p class="output"></p>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_add
Take a look at this website you can learn a lot from it ;)

Comment: Rick this is exactlly what i wanted, thank you

Comment: What is the question here? You say you know you can add more options through looping and `createElement`... so go for it? Try it! If you have an issue with it, then ask a question about that issue.

Comment: i'v got that somewhere wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic code :

```
let select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
let option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Starwars 8";
option.value = "Starwars 8"
select.add(option);
```

Do you need more :  adding a listener on "#add" ?